# Using Panda/Numpy to search matching string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to solve this for a while now but have not yet gotten anywhere. My goal is to search a string in a column called 'WORDS' and return the 'INDEXED_NUMBER'. For example, if I searched 'aaa', it should return me 0 as shown in the table below.

[image: Sample table]

I am using python panda and possibly is trying numpy as well.
Below is a sample of code I've tried:

```
def WordToIndexwithjustPanda():
    referenceDF[referenceDF['WORDS'].str.contains('aaa')]
    #I was hoping that it will grab me the row with the word 'aaa' but 
    #it is not returning me anything
```

and

```
def WordToIndexwithNumpy():
    np.where(referenceDF["WORDS"].str.contains('aaa'))
    #I think this is wrong but I am not sure how is this wrong
```

I hope you guys can guide me to the right way of using this. I am using anaconda prompt and jupyter notebook as an additional note. I have imported panda and numpy.

Thanks in advance. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and dont forget add `return` to fuction, also for return scalar need `iat` for select first value of filtered `Series` with `if-else` if filtering return no rows:

```
def WordToIndexwithjustPanda():
    a = referenceDF.loc[referenceDF['WORDS'].str.contains('aaa'), 'INDEXED_NUMBER']
    return 'No match' if a.empty else a.iat[0]
```

You can use also parameter in function for check first occurence of value:

```
referenceDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'WORDS': ['aaa','aaas','aactive','aadvantage','aaker'],
    'INDEXED_NUMBER': list(range(5))
})
print (referenceDF)
   INDEXED_NUMBER       WORDS
0               0         aaa
1               1        aaas
2               2     aactive
3               3  aadvantage
4               4       aaker

def WordToIndexwithjustPanda(val):
    a = referenceDF.loc[referenceDF['WORDS'].str.contains(val), 'INDEXED_NUMBER']
    return 'No match' if a.empty else a.iat[0]
print (WordToIndexwithjustPanda('aaa'))
0
print (WordToIndexwithjustPanda('bbb'))
No match
```

Comment: Owh, thanks! I definitely will give a read at loc. I'm still learning this library so there's a gap in my knowledge. Thanks again yeah. XDD

Comment: @user3480400 - I try improve solution with parameter, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to implement your algorithm using a generator:

```
def WordToIndexwithjustPanda():
    return next((i for i, j in zip(df['INDEXED_NUMBER', df['WORDS']) \
                 if 'aaa' in j), 'No match')
```

Strictly speaking it uses pandas only partially in that it uses the iterative functionality of `pd.Series`.

Comment: Owh, I never knew I can write this way. I'm gunna give it a go. XDDD